# Why am I not getting Spring Security Login Error Messages?

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security, tiles2

Using Spring Security 3 along with Struts 2 and Tiles 2, I have a login page that appears when it is supposed to and performs the login as expected -- however when I enter bad user credentials I am returned to the login page with no information about what went wrong. I've checked all my configuration parameters and I can't see where the problem is.

My Spring Security XML config is as follows:

```
 <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('AUTH_MANAGE_USERS')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/group/**" access="hasRole('AUTH_MANAGE_USERS')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403.html"/>
    <form-login  login-page="/public/login.do" always-use-default-target="false"/>
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/public/home.do"/>
</http>
```

My Struts Action looks like this:

```
<package name="public" namespace="/public" extends="secure">
    <action name="login">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">tiles.login.panel</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">tiles.login.panel</result>
        <result name="error">/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="logout">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">/j_spring_security_logout</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

And the login.jsp page (part of the tile) looks for the exception from Spring Security...

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
   <span class="actionError">
   Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br/><br/>
        Reason: <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/>.
  </span>
</c:if>
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?   Thanks in advance for any/all replies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring Security doesn't set `param.login_error` automatically. You need to do it manaully as follows:

```
<form-login  
    login-page="/public/login.do" 
    authentication-failure-url = "/public/login.do?login_error=1"
    always-use-default-target="false"/>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! I knew it was something in the config I was missing. Unfortunately the SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION is giving a very technical error that I can't show to a user. Reason: localhost:10389; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: localhost:10389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]. -- because I am authenticating against LDAP.  Is there a more meaningful message in scope I can present to the user -- or just stick with Bad user id or password??

Comment: @Griff: I think `Bad user id or password` is better for security reasons, so that malicious person can't see what is wrong.

Comment: Strange. Spring's docs say "Defaults to /spring_security_login?login_error, which will be automatically handled by the automatic login page generator...". 

Can it work with HTML (and not JSP)?

Comment: @OhadR: If you set a custom `login-page`, automatic login page generator doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion for helping with the conversion of error messages like in the final comment is to use an AuthenticationFailureHandler to map different exception types to different error codes that the ui-layer code can lookup unique messages for. It looks like:

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login" 
    authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>

<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?reason=login_error"/>
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <map>
        <entry><key><value>org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException</value></key>
            <value>/login?reason=user_locked</value></entry>

            <entry><key><value>org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException</value></key>
            <value>/login?reason=user_disabled</value></entry>

            <entry><key><value>org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException</value></key>
            <value>/login?reason=connection</value></entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```